# Jahn-Teller Distortion: How to compare magnitudes (in Cu2+ complexes)?

Tags: coordination-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory, electronic-configuration, transition-metals, symmetry

> Octahedral complex of copper(II) undergo structural distortion (Jahn-Teller). Which one of the given copper(II) complexes will who the **maximum** structural distortion? (en - ethylenediamine)

> (A) $[Cu(H_2O)_6]SO_4$

> (B) $[Cu(en)(H_2O)_4]SO_4$

> (C) $cis-[Cu(en)_2Cl_2]$

> (D) $trans-[Cu(en)_2Cl_2]$

The answer given is A.

**How do I compare the magnitude of Jahn-Teller distortion on $e_g^3$ complexes?**

---

I have subjectively understood the JT effect: $Cu^{2+}$ in its $d^9 -t_{2g}^6e_g^3$ configuration has an asymmetric configuration, so the octahedral complex breaks symmetry by distorting, usually by lengthening (z-out) along the $d_{z^2}$ orbital or shortening (z-in)

However in the question, all the complexes have the same configuration.
Is it something to do with the strength of the ligands?

---

This question is from the second shift of the [JEE Main](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination_%E2%80%93_Main)
exam held on July 29, 2022. There is a possibility the answer is wrong, however I would still like to know how to compare distortion.
I have referenced the following material:

1. JD Lee (Sudarshan Guha): does not compare magnitudes
2. [Libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Coordination_Chemistry/Structure_and_Nomenclature_of_Coordination_Compounds/Coordination_Numbers_and_Geometry/Jahn-Teller_Distortions): says "stronger M-L interactions increase chance of observing JT" . That sounds too vague.

I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: Well until it defines "maximum structural distortion" I have no idea what it means. The en complexes will already be distorted from Oh before J-T is even considered, how are we measuring distortion on top of distortion?

Comment: @IanBush what's "Oh"? Is it a group theory thing?

Comment: Sigh. Yes. It is short for Octahedral, and represents the point group for that symmetry. It is where labels such as $t_{2g}$ come from.